# Upvoting a First Posts review audit doesn't actually upvote the post

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review-audits, first-post-review

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42488315/4032703) recently showed up as a [First Posts review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/15632056). I (correctly) upvoted it as a reasonable post and passed the review audit; however, when I looked at it later, my upvote hadn't actually been applied. (I was able to manually upvote it later).

Shouldn't upvotes on review audits actually be applied? The post in question actually *was* helpful/useful to me (in addition to being a good answer).

Comment: Do you see the correct vote count in those audits, when you first open the audit?

Comment: @Cerbrus It showed the number of upvotes it had before I voted. Mine definitely wasn't applied.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are the downvotes due to people disagreeing with the proposed change or something about the post itself? (I do think that @Stijn suggested a good reason not to make this change in his answer, so I tend to think that I may stand corrected as well).

Comment: @EJoshuaS probably, or just as likely that you tagged this as a bug, when it is it not a bug

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is intentional. Audits are automatically chosen based on certain criteria and reused to show to multiple users. Letting votes count would affect the post score disproportionally.

Remember that the point of audits is to verify if the reviewer is doing a good job, rather than verifying whether the post is good.

Comment: Thanks, that's definitely a legitimate reason to keep the current behavior. I flagged my original post asking the moderators to tag it as "by design."

Comment: Regardless of whether it is intentional or not, I think that the way it is is wrong and should be changed. If a post meets the criteria for a known good audit (no downvotes, no close votes, etc) then it must be a decent post, why not reward the post?

Comment: @TinyGiant Just because a post isn't closed, and already has a few upvotes, does *not* automatically mean it's a good post.  Additionally, the people voting on it are highly unlikely to be subject matter experts on the material at hand, and as such aren't likely to be qualified to judge the technical merits of the post.

Comment: @servy If they are upvoting in review when they shouldn't be upvoting (for example, they don't understand the post well enough to determine if it is a good post), they should have their audit privileges revoked.  If the upvote was legitimate, it should stand.  Why are we "passing" people while assuming *they did the wrong action*?

Comment: @Yakk If we can assume that people are consistently able to take the correct action in /review then why do we even have audits in the first place?  The whole reason that the audits are there is because a *significant* portion of reviewers don't review properly.

Comment: @Servy Except, if they should **only pass a review audit if their action was correct**.  If their action was correct, the upvote should stand.  Contrawise, if their upvote should not stand, their action was incorrect, **and they should fail the audit**.  Both stating "their upvote shouldn't count, they aren't subject matter experts, they should not have upvoted that" and "they did the correct action by upvoting, they should pass the audit" doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @Yakk It's not that we *know* they aren't subject matter experts and *shouldn't* upvote, but rather that, of the hundreds of people that are likely to end up seeing that audit only a handful of them are likely to be subject matter experts, and we don't know who those people are.  Additionally, as mentioned before, this is a very inorganic means of drawing attention to the post (showing it to hundreds of people who likely wouldn't have otherwise seen it).

Comment: @Servy So you are saying that most of the people who upvote should have failed the audit?

Comment: @Yakk No, I'm saying that most of the people took an action that we don't have any possible way of knowing the validity of, so we can't fail them on it, but, in aggregate, we'll be making the site worse if we apply.

Comment: @Servy Which means that the majority(?) of people who you think should pass this audit are doing a harmful action, and yet you think this is good for the site because in this specific case we can just pass them and block their probably harmful action and let them continue their same patterm of probably harmful behavior on the rest of the queue where we let it stand and don't notice it, because dillution is the solution to pollution.  Well, that is a position, and possibly right one, but seems icky to me.

Comment: @Yakk The majority of people taking the action are doing an action that we don't have the means to evaluate the validity of.  You can't fail them and block them from reviewing for doing an action that you simply can't evaluate the validity of.

Comment: @Servy You are the one who is claiming that most of them are doing something invalid.  Your solution is to "in this case, don't let them do it, because the vote is probably crap", then proceed to let them upvote (or other action) equally invalid cases another ~50 times because "they passed the audit".  Every invalid audit action is balanced with ~50 other chances to be equally invalid; if we don't trust them to upvote on the audit, we shouldn't do it on the other 50 cases.  If we trust them on the other ~50 cases, we should trust them on the audit.

Comment: @Yakk Do you really not understand the difference between, "an action that we don't have the means to evaluate the validity of" and "an action that we can prove is unequivocally wrong"?  There are audits that exist that are designed to look for people upvoting posts that they shouldn't.  This isn't that type of audit though.  This is an audit designed to test if someone is flagging content that they shouldn't.  It's the known-bad audits that are designed to test if people upvote/mark okay posts that they shouldn't.

Comment: @Servy My problem is the same is true of the *other* 50 review actions they do between audits.  The only difference is the "harm" is *more obvious* when the "bad actions" are concentrated on the audit case.  In short, by blocking the "harm" on audit cases, we obscure the harm.  If it is true that the majority of people, given marginal content they are not qualified to upvote, upvote, those upvotes are as bad as the ones we are blocking on the audit case with the same situation.  If we are blocking upvotes on audits, we should block all upvotes in the queue.